# PHP 8.1.3 Why does a method call fail to start when called?

Tags: php

I am trying to create an MVC template for my site and am working on testing authentication code.  No errors show up on the screen or log files, however, the code does not complete.  It simply dies when I try calling findUser().

When I call from my Authentication controller to the associated class/method, nothing happens.  Here is the code for the area.  Note the echo statements, and how I never get "Begin: tAuthentication - findUser method"

I am using PHP 8.1.3_1 and the latest version of Apache.

```
    # File: InitializeMVC.php
require_once CORE_PATH . 'Database.php';


# File: AuthenticationControl.php
require_once MODEL_PATH . 'tAuthentication.php';

class Authentication {
   public object $AuthenticationModel;
        
   public function __construct(){
      echo "Begin: AuthenticationControl | construct: " .  " <br />";
      $AuthenticationModel = new tAuthentication;
   }

   public function login() {
      echo "Begin: AuthenticationControl | login: "  . " <br />";   
      $data['Uname'] = "testuser";
      echo "Data loaded.  Go to model.<br />";
      $userid = $AuthenticationModel->findUser($data['Uname']);
      echo "Return to AuthenticationControl with userid. <br />";

    } 
}

# File: tAuthentication.php
class tAuthentication extends Database {

   public function __construct() {
      echo "Begin: AuthenticationModel | construct: " .  " <br />";
      $this->db = new Database;

   public function findUser($username){
      echo "Begin: tAuthentication - findUser method <br />";
      $this->db->query('SELECT PeopleID FROM vAuthenticate WHERE username = :username OR email = :username');
      $this->db->bind(':username', $username);
      $row = $this->db->GetData();
   }
}

# Begin: AuthenticationControl | construct:
# Begin: tAuthentication | construct:
# Begin: AuthenticationControl | login:
# Data loaded. Go to model.
```

Comment: Your code doesn't include the string `Begin: tAuthentication | construct` so it looks like your example doesn't match the expected output. In any case, according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php, parent constructors are not called implicitly which may be unexpected to you.

Comment: @msbit I did not know about the page link you gave me.  Thanks!.  The output was manually typed (now fixed).  The problem is when my Authentication Controller class uses its login method to call another class' (tAuthentication) method called 'findUser'.  The echo right before the call happens, but the first action inside the method (an echo) never shows up.

Comment: As the PHP docs said you can invoke the parent constructor manually from the child constructor, via `parent::__construct()`. You'll likely need to include the code where these controllers are created and used to allow us to give more insight.

Comment: I used to try and rewrite MVC and then I realised its a waste of time, plenty of smarter people have already done it, just pick a framework and go learn it mate, not trying to be a prick but it will save you years of pain lol

Comment: @Dale Yeah...  I agree with you there.  The MVC part is not bothering me.  It's the fact that my Authentication method, login(), calls a method in another class, namely the findUser() method in the tAuthentication class.  That call never goes through.  I never get the findUser() method to fire off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You forgot to use `$this` in `Authentication::__construct()` and `Authentication::login()` as well.
   If you want to refer to an object's property from within its own method you need to use `$this`. Otherwise it refers to a local variable within the method if it exists or to an undefined variable.  The latter also generates a notice except if this is an assignment to the formerly undefined variable.

   So in these methods you need to write `$this->AuthenticationModel` instead of `$AuthenticationModel`.
2. In the `Authentication::login()` method you are also referring to an array's key without defining the variable itself as an array:
   `$data['Uname'] = "testuser";`...

   `$data` should be defined as an array like `$data = [];` or `$data = array();` before accessing a key of it.